# Convert this SQL statement to Laravel ORM

Tags: laravel, orm

How can I do this in Laravel ORM?

```
SELECT
    s.id,
    s.name AS NAME,
    COALESCE(su.cnt, 0) AS SUBJECTs,
    COALESCE(e.marks, 0) AS MARKS
FROM student s
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT student_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM subject
    GROUP BY student_id
) su
    ON s.id = su.student_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT student_id, SUM(mark) AS marks
    FROM exam
    GROUP BY student_id
) e
    ON s.id = e.student_id;
```

I want to join between STUDENT and SUBJECT, STUDENT and EXAM.  The problem is happening when I join the third table, it duplicates the results.

Comment: Add 'group by s.id'. By add this query you will get single record instead of duplicate records

Comment: Surely this is a SQL problem pure and simple? I should think about editing the tags.

Comment: Do you have eloquent models set up for these tables?

Comment: yes i do, @RossWilson

Comment: Are do you have the relationships set up between `Student` -> `Subject` and `Student` -> `Exam`?

Answer (score 0):

This is

```
DB::table('student as su')->selectRaw("
  su.id,
  su.name,
  COALESCE(su.cnt, 0) as SUBJECTS,
  COALESCE(e.marks, 0) as MARKS
")->leftJoin(DB::raw("(
  SELECT student_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM subject
  GROUP BY student_id
) su"), 's.id', '=', 'su.student_id')
->leftJoin(DB::raw("(
  SELECT student_id, SUM(mark) AS marks
  FROM exam
  GROUP BY student_id
) e"), 's.id', '=', 'e.student_id')
```

Comment: i see that you repeared "su" forboth student and subjects in line 1 and 10 @Malkhazi Dartsmelidze

Comment: Yes, that's mistake, I didn't see it. hope code works after Changing it.
please consider to upvote if it works

Comment: i still have small issue in the last SUM of the marks, it displays on one mark@Makhazi Dartsmelidze